# Add Maven as item type on jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I deployed jenkins in tomcat server , I tried to add maven project by specifying  maven_home  in global Tools configuration but when I click on  new item  I can't find maven project  as an option I restart jenkins but without result .

I use Tomcat 8 and jenkins 2.19.1

So how could i add Maven as an item type?

Comment: Which version of Jenkins do you use? Did you install the recommended plugins? The maven project type comes with the [Maven Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin)

Comment: for jenkins i use v 2.19.1 yeah and in global Tools configuration i find maven and i specified maven home path and a name